# update on conflict do nothing postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to update a table so that I can remove the prepended zeros from one of the columns. I want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE oh_person SET identifier = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM identifier)
```

The issue is that some of the rows already have the identifier without the prepended zeros, and since this column is meant to be unique, it throws an error in those instances. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
UPDATE oh_person SET identifier = TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM identifier) ON CONFLICT (identifier) DO NOTHING
```

I know that that particular query would not be possible but is there some other syntax that would achieve that?

Comment: Can you give us a few examples of identifiers with prepended zeros that work just fine and some that throw an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table oh_person(identifier text unique);
insert into oh_person 
values ('012'), ('0012'), ('0015'), ('015');
```

Use [anonymous code block](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html):

```
do $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    for r in
        select identifier
        from oh_person
        where left(identifier, 1) = '0'
    loop
    begin
        update oh_person
        set identifier = trim(leading '0' from identifier)
        where identifier = r.identifier;
    exception
        when unique_violation then
            raise notice '% not updated', r.identifier;
    end;
    end loop;
end $$;

NOTICE:  0012 not updated
NOTICE:  015 not updated
```

Result:

```
select * from oh_person;

 identifier 
------------
 0012
 015
 12
 15
(4 rows)
```